# How to play bagfile from a specific point( i.e not from start of the bagfile)?

Tags: gps, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Bag file is taken from lidar and that file contains the following information.

```
    path:        file2.bag
    version:     2.0
    duration:    3:47s (227s)
    start:       Nov 08 2012 16:19:48.77 (1352371788.77)
    end:         Nov 08 2012 16:23:36.39 (1352372016.39)
    size:        1.6 GB
    messages:    28305
    compression: none [1847/1847 chunks]
    types:       augv_msgs/InertialData     [757c72354c42518ae68ece93194dc095]
    gps_common/GPSFix          [3db3d0a7bc53054c67c528af84710b70]
    sensor_msgs/Image          [060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743]
    velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan [50804fc9533a0e579e6322c04ae70566]
    topics:      /GPSFix                  11383 msgs    : gps_common/GPSFix         
                 /InertialData            11383 msgs    : augv_msgs/InertialData    
                 /basler_node/image_raw    2590 msgs    : sensor_msgs/Image         
                 /velodyne_packets         2949 msgs    :velodyne_msgs/VelodyneScan
```

/GPSFIX contains Latitude and longitude informations. I want to play the bag file from specific latitude and logitude value. How should i do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/83411/how-to-play-bagfile-from-a-specific-point(-i.e-not-from-start-of-the-bagfile)?/) by [Bindu](https://answers.ros.org/users/5524/bindu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2013-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can start playing file from specific time with parameter `-s`, but you will have to find this time yourself. It can be done either manually or via [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API). Basically, you will have to iterate through all the messages and test them against necessary conditions, e.g. GPS coordinates. For this kind of tasks I personally prefer Python, but there is C++ API as well. You can find some code snippets [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook).

For details on `rosbag play` commandline usage, please see [rosbag/Commandline/play](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline#play).

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would suggest that you filter your bag file, using your desired latitude/longitude as arguments for the filter, and then play the new bag file. more info on how to filter bag files, can be found in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/56935/how-to-remove-a-tf-from-a-ros-bag/#56940), for example.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-09-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1